# AutoHotkey type entries from ListBox

Tags: listbox, autohotkey, reusability

I am new to AutoHotkey and have no programming experience, so sorry to ask what to many of you may be a very mundane question.
One of my main uses for AutoHotkey will be to complete data in records I keep from an AutoHotkey ListBox.
Using replies to other forum questions I have a working script as follows:

```
:*:\lb::
Gui, Add, ListBox, h100 vLB, apple||bannana|cantaloup|kiwi|orange|pomegranate|strawberry
Gui, Add, Button, Default, Input
Gui, Show
return

ButtonInput:
Gui, Submit
SendInput, %LB%
Gui, Destroy
Return
```

I wanted to include “, NoHide” after “Gui, Submit” above, but if I do that the script no longer works.
Is there any way I can use the hotstring just once to launch the ListBox then have it stay on the desktop, so I can select other items as and when I get to other places in the records I keep where I need to select a different entry from the Listbox? If I remove "Gui, Destroy" from the script, the script also no longer works, so that does not appear to be the solution.
Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: I don't know if you are interested in this, but I expanded your app with an upload/download facility and the possibility to insert items with a sort of Copy. Let me know and I'll share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this modified script, which, when started, stays on top until YOU close it. Hope that that is what you wanted. If you close the Gui, the AHK script will close as well.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

;:*:\lb::
Gui, Add, ListBox, h100 vLB, apple||bannana|cantaloup|kiwi|orange|pomegranate|strawberry
Gui, Add, Button, Default, Input
Gui, +AlwaysOnTop
Gui, Show
return

ButtonInput:
Gui, Submit, NoHide
;MsgBox, %LB%
ControlSend,, %LB%, Part of your App title in the windows bar OR ahk_class ABCD (via AHK Windows Spy)
Return

GuiClose:
GuiEscape:
Gui, Destroy
ExitApp
```

## Update:

I could not help it, but had to add some more functionality. You can now double click on an item and it automatically moves to the next cell.

```
#SingleInstance Force
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent

Gui, Add, ListBox, h100 vMyListBox gMyListBox, apple|bannana|cantaloup|kiwi|orange|pomegranate|strawberry
Gui, Add, Button, Default, Input
Gui, +AlwaysOnTop
Gui, Show
return

MyListBox:
if A_GuiControlEvent <> DoubleClick
    return
GuiControlGet, MyListBox  ; Retrieve the ListBox's current selection.
Send, !{Esc}
Sleep, 200
SendInput, %MyListBox%{Tab}
return

ButtonInput:
Gui, Submit, NoHide
Send, !{Esc}
Sleep, 200
SendInput, %MyListBox%{Tab}
Return

GuiClose:
GuiEscape:
Gui, Destroy
ExitApp
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help - instead of typing the selection from the ListBox, which is what I'm trying to get it to do, it pops up a message box. If I remove "MsgBox, %LB%
;"and just leave "SendInput, %LB%" it no longer works? Is there a way to type the ListBox selection whilst still leaving the Gui on top? Any further assistance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: That is because you are sending to your own GUI. Use ControlSend. You need to know the Title or ID of the app you are sending to. I'll add this to the script.

Comment: If the application changes, you have to either capture the application before you create your gui or add the range of applications to a list and test which of those is currently open.

Comment: Okay. Wonderful - I've been trying to do this for nearly 2 weeks. Thank you so much.

Comment: Is it working? When the answer was helpful, please "Accept" the answer by clicking on the WHITE "Check-mark" next to the answer, to turn it GREEN. Thank you! Clicking the check-mark will give credits to the person who submitted the answer and will mark the question as answered. See: [Accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/210367)

Comment: Oh, one alternative is to still use regular send, but add a Send, !{Esc} and Sleep, 100 before you send the data. With [Alt]+[Esc], you switch focus to the previous application, before sending...

Comment: @RogerAbbett, I could not help it, but added some extra functionality and wanted to share that with you!

Comment: Well I have no idea how you knew I would be using this with Excel, but you were absolutely right and it works brilliantly and I noticed without needing to enter the App title from the windows bar. Exactly what I wanted. I'm delighted with it and am truly grateful for all your help!