# Program to put text into LibreOffice document

Tags: c#, windows, libreoffice

I'm trying to make a program in C# which should put text into an opened LibreOffice document (Writer).

A first the user can make some decisions about the text (saved to string variables) and when clicking on a button it should put the text from these strings to the document.

How can I do that?

Comment: Hi mrgerbik2013 , check my updated answer ,If my answer helps you than don't forget to mark as answer and upvote :)

Comment: If you don't want to use a library, and you want to create an easy to use exe file, you could use AutoHotKey. Look here for an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451040/autohotkey-type-entries-from-listbox). AutoHotKey makes relatively large exe's. I use something similar to store up to 20 clipboard texts.

Comment: Look at these answers. AOLD is old and not maintained API
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390006/openoffice-and-net/12439384

Answer (score 5):

Libre Office uses [Open Document Format (ODF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) (its actually an XML based format and is usually compressed by using zip) which is an easy format to work with ,I have found AODL to be the only openSource library (check below links) and I'm also sure .NET libraries can do the heavy lifting for you, here are some tutorials and links to help you out.

1. [AODL allows your application to support the OpenDocument Format.(OpenSource .NET Library)](https://code.google.com/p/aodl2/)
2. [How to Read and Write ODF/ODS File](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38425/How-to-Read-and-Write-ODF-ODS-Files-OpenDocument-S)
3. [Read and write ODF/ODS files (OpenDocument Spreadsheets)](http://www.go4expert.com/articles/read-write-odf-ods-files-opendocument-t19110/)